# При парсинге крашится приложение(возвращает пустой массив с фото). Остальные данные парсятся(друзья, группы, новости)

Tags: swift

```
  enum ApiMethod {
    case friends
    case groups
    case photos(ownerId:Int)
    case searchGroups(searchText:String)
    case postNews(nextFeed: String)
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .friends:
            return "/method/friends.get"
        case .groups:
            return "/method/groups.get"
        case .photos:
            return "/method/photos.getAll"
        case .searchGroups:
            return "/method/groups.search"
        case .postNews:
            return "/method/newsfeed.get"
        }
    }
    var parameters: [String: String] {
        switch self {
        case .friends:
            return ["fields":"photo_100"]
        case .groups:
            return ["extended":"1"]
        case let .photos(ownerId):
            return ["owner_id":String(ownerId)]
        case let .searchGroups(searchText):
            return ["q": searchText]
        case let .postNews(nextFeed):
            return ["filters":"post",
                    "start_from":nextFeed]
        }
    }
}

private func request(_ method: ApiMethod,
                     completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
    var componets = URLComponents()
    componets.scheme = "https"
    componets.host = "api.vk.com"
    componets.path = method.path
    let defaultQueryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: session),
        URLQueryItem(name: "v", value: "5.126")
    ]
    let maethodQueryItems = method.parameters.map {
        URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
    }
    componets.queryItems = defaultQueryItems + maethodQueryItems
    
    guard let url = componets.url else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(data)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

 

   struct FriendPhotos: Decodable {
            let sizes: [SizePhoto]
            var id: Int
            var ownerId: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sizes
        case id
        case ownerId = "owner_id"
    }
    
    static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["ownerId"]
    }
}

struct SizePhoto: Decodable {
    let height: Int
    let url: String
    let width: Int
    let type: String
}



 func getPhoto(ownerId: Int, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void ) {
    request(.photos(ownerId: ownerId)) { (data) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let arrayPhotosFriend = try JSONDecoder().decode(VKResponse<FriendPhotos>.self,
                                                             from: data)
            
            var photosFriend: [String] = []
            
            for i in 0...arrayPhotosFriend.items.count {
                if let urlPhoto = arrayPhotosFriend.items[i].sizes.last?.url { // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
                    photosFriend.append(urlPhoto)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                completion([arrayPhotosFriend.items.last?.sizes.last?.url ?? ""])
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion([])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выходите за пределы массива при обращении к items, нужно вот так:

```
for i in 0..<arrayPhotosFriend.items.count
```